# Get parent data when child value matches

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I would like to get parent data when my child value matches with "id22"

```
<servers>
<someservers>
  <owner>id0</owner>
  <serverCode>fefwewf</serverCode>
  <address>345345</address>
  <authCertHash>efref</authCertHash>
  <authCertHash>erferf=</authCertHash>
  <client>id1</client>
  <client>id22</client>
</someservers>
<someservers>
  <owner>id33</owner>
  <serverCode>f</sewewefrverCode>
  <address>234234234</address>
  <authCertHash>sdfs</authCertHash>
  <client>id27</client>
</someservers>
</server>
```

Currently im trying as following:

```
$server = $xml -> xpath('//someservers//client='id22');
echo $server->address;
```

But it's not working, I get error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object in...
```

I hope to get output:

```
345345
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` only supports Xpath expressions that return an node list, so it can convert them into an array of `SimpleXMLElement`instances.

@andersson already explained that you expression only returns the existence of the specified client element. You need to use a condition. This will return an array with matching `SimpleXMLElement` objects as the elements.

```
$servers = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$server = $servers->xpath('//someservers[client="id22"]')[0];
echo $server->address;
```

Output:

```
345345
```

`DOMXpath::evaluate()` is able to return the scalar value directly:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath= new DOMXpath($document);
echo $xpath->evaluate('string(//someservers[client="id22"]/address)');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `XPath` `//someservers//client='id22` intend to return boolean `true`/`false` value, but not element or its text content

Try to use below `XPath` expression

```
//someservers[client='id22']/address/text()
```

that should return required `"345345"`

Comment: But what If i want to get other values too under this parent item? I thought I could do it like:
    echo $server->address;
    echo $server->owner;

or even with foreach.

Comment: Btw, when I tried to echo like this, I got "Array" as a return.

Comment: You can use `//someservers[client='id22']/*/text()` to get all values